# Sed pattern in a date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: bash, date, sed, centos

My issue is changing a part of a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` to `mm/dd/2016` or for learning purposes let's say `mm/dd/yyyy` to `mm/02/yyyy`.

In my file I'm going to cat in:

```
05/06/1989
05/06/2001
01/03/2015
```

Using sed to replace that file, I am running commands such as:

```
sed 's|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/2016|g'
```

This printed out the exact same thing.

So then I tried maybe changing the year by doing:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/2016/g'
```

but this didn't do anything either.

Comment: `echo 01/03/2015 | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/2016/g'` works fine here. What commands are you running *exactly*?

Comment: @Kenney my exact code right now is. cat file.csv | awk -F '{print $13}' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/2016/g'

Comment: @Kenney yes you are right, my code has it. cat file.csv | awk -F "," '{print $13}' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/2016/g' testing without piping now. When I run it without the | sed I get an error from awk.

Comment: I recommend you to use the `date` command, it's useful to know. You can loop over the file contents and match the format with `-d` and put your output string `+%`. E.g. `date -d"05/06/1989" "+%m/02/%y"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed only:

```
echo "01/03/2015" | sed -e 's|\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)|year \3 month \1 day \2|'
```

When you need to skip the first 12 fields, you can use `cut -F, -13-` or use

```
echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,01/03/2015" | sed -e 's|\([^,]*,\)\{12\}\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)|year \4 month \2 day \3|'
```

Explanation:
You can mark matches with the construction using `(something_to_match)` to mark a match and a number to show what is marked. The `()` and numbers are all treated special, so they all need to be escaped with backslashes.

```
sed 's/\(match1\)......\(match2\)/and now \1 and \2/'
```

When you write it this way, don't forget that the characters between the matches should match too (the dots are actualy wildcards for one char each).

`[0-9][0-9]` you understand, but you can also say repeat `[0-9]` two (or four) times. Give the number in curly brackets, and the brackets are special so escape them.
When you want to use the curly brackets more often, the first line can be changed in

```
echo "01/03/2015" | sed -e 's|\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)|year \3 month \1 day \2|'
```

Parsing the csv is easy with cut. Using the sed solution is just a challenge for learning sed better. What is that `\([^,]*,\)`?
Yes you are right, the `\(\)` is for matching the stuff in between. I want to match one field followed by a `,`. How can you say you want to match a string without a `,` ? You use the negatioin `^` in the character class `[,]`, so `[^,]` will match any character except the `,`. Only once.
Using `[^,]*` will match a string without a `,`.
The second `,` in `\([^,]*,\)` is ... just a plain `,`.
The complete match is a the first field followed by a `,`.
Now match the first 12 csv fields with `{12}`, but do not forget the backslashes.
In input string has slashes, so use another character like the `|` (you already found that):

```
sed 's|from|to|'
# or everything filled in
sed -e 's|\([^,]*,\)\{12\}\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)|year \4 month \2 day \3|'
          ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^    ^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^           ^^^     ^^^     ^^
          field+,   repeat    month          day            year          recall   recall   recall
```

Comment: Hey can you break code down for me? I don't understand the whole ^, and {} and what are you doing in the end with "|year \3 month \1 day \2|"

Comment: It's broken now. The pipes were your idea, `\nr` is a recall construction (see edit).

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect.

Comment: In that case you can hit the `V` next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is simple, but I switch over to Perl when the regular expressions are more complicated.  In the example above, converting 01/03/2015 to 01/02/2015:

```
echo 01/03/2015 | perl -pe 's/([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9]{4})/\1\/02\/\3/'
```

There are three regular expression backreferences: month, day and year.  I added back month and year, and changed the day to 02.  The '{4}' in the regular expression means that there must be four matches.

If you just want to change the year, it would be:

```
echo 01/03/2015 | perl -pe 's/([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9]{4})/\1\/\2\/2016/'
```